# What kind of 3D models can QGIS's 3D View handle?

Tags: qgis, 3d-model, 3d-map

I'm trying to get QGIS to load a 3D model made in sketchup, as seen here:
[image]

However, the model is not loading in the QGIS 3D Viewer.  Any suggestions?  QGIS does not give any input on what type of file they're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good question - I have luck with the .obj format. Try the beachball here: https://free3d.com/3d-model/beach-ball-v2--259926.html.

[image]

Comment: The beachball works, thanks!

Any idea how I might get this dae file working?

Comment: Only got the .obj format working

Comment: I googled for a dae to obj converter and was able to successfully get my new obj file imported.  Thanks!